# Sorting "My Account" Links in Magento

Tags: xml, magento, magento-1.9

I wish to add a **Logout** link to the My Account page(s) in Magento (currently using 1.9.0.1) and have the following code in `local.xml` which works:

```
<customer_account>
  <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
    <action method="addLink" module="customer" translate="label">
      <name>logout</name>
      <path>customer/account/logout</path>
      <label>Logout</label>
    </action>
  </reference>
</customer_account>
```

However, I wish to ensure said **Logout** link appears at the *bottom*, whilst keeping it within the *same* list. I'm wondering if there's a suitable way to achieve this via XML, or whether I'll have to weed it out via a front-end template.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortuanately, there is no such provision to do this via XML. But if you use the above code in `local.xml`, then the link that you have added will be shown at last. So the easiest solution is use `local.xml` itself for adding such links.

If you want to know why it is not possible via xml, then this is the reason. When you try to `addLink`, what Magento does is, appending the item to an array. There is only provision to add a link. No provision to remove a link.

Since `local.xml` file is processed at last, the link that you have added via above script will append the link to last of that array and thus you will see the `logout` link at last.

But if you are interested to do this via an observer, then you can use the event `controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after`. If you use this, then you can grab all the links like this.

```
<?php
public function yourObserverMethod(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $fullaction = $observer->getEvent()->getAction()->getFullActionName();
    if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()
        && strpos($fullaction, 'customer_account') !== false
    ) {
        $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();
        $navigationBlock = $layout->getBlock('customer_account_navigation');
        if ($navigationBlock !== false) {

             //here you get all links.do anything with this array.
            $links = $navigationBlock->getLinks();
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: I think a Magento extension was using the aforementioned `controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after` method (which would explain why my **Logout** link wasn't appearing at the bottom). Thank you!

Comment: why it didn't appear?? i am curious to know the reason